# How to create an overlay to automatically load on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

I'm trying to figure out how to create an overlay box that automatically loads on the page load and then has an okay button for the user to click to make it go away.

I'm looking for something similar to this http://laurenconrad.com/

See how the overlay pops up with a pink semi transparent background and a sign up box in the center? That doesn't show up every time though, only once a week I believe. I'm looking for something similar to that to give the option of my site visitors to subscribe.

I've been trying to follow various tutorials but nothing seems to be working very well. I don't know much about overlays or scripts so any help with the CSS, HTMl, and the script would be super helpful! Thank you!

Rebecca

Comment: well, use jQuery and jQuery UI with its modal dialog: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/. of course if you want to show that only once every week, you need to store that information (last shown). you could do that using cookies, but i would use the localStorage

Answer (score 2):

To do this, i'd use jQuery. Create the overlay in HTML/CSS and place the overlay div at the beginning of the  tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // check cookie
    var visited = $.cookie("visited")

    // load overlay if they haven't visited
    if (visited == null) {
        $('#overlay').fadeIn();     
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes');  
    }

    // set cookie
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
});

$('button').click(function () {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(200, "linear");
});
```

This code will load your div with the id "overlay" and when the hide button is clicked, the div will fade out. You could have the div fade out just by clicking the overlay div if you preferred. By using this:

```
$('#overlay').click(function () {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(200, "linear");
});
```

Here's a fiddle to show you what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/andaywells/jWcqZ/17/

Comment: I got Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for this line `var visited = $.cookie("visited")` any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the overlay loaded on the page but hidden.

Then use jQ's dom on ready event to show the overlay.

This is the simplest of overlays you can do: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/6gaND/

```
$('#overlay').css({'opacity': 0, 'display': "block"});
$('#overlay').animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000).on("click", function() {
    $('#overlay').animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000);
});
```

Enjoy!

Comment: In the fiddle, change the positioning property of `#overlay` from `position:absolute` to `position:fixed` to cover the entire page. :)